# How can I check my banner application on my actual android device that is it working correctly or not?

Tags: android

I have developed a simple application using SDK(Android: 3.2[API-13]) for, to display Google banners. 
I have tow problems in this application.

Problem No.1:
I have checked the application it runs on emulator but how can i check it that it working correctly or not?

Problem No.2:
I want to run the application on my physical Android device using Android version 2.3.3. What changes I need to do in the application to run it on my Android device using Android version 2.3.3.?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.farman.banner"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyBannerActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
              android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>


    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


</manifest
```

>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ans 1 :-You have to install it in the Device and Check it.
Ans 2 :-To Run it in the 2.3.3 version,you have edit the files as below:-

- project.properties OR default.properties(Only 1 of the 2 may 
                                         be present in the root folder)
              Here...Change the value of target=android-10
- Androidmanifest.xml
    Here...Check and Change the value of
              `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" />` as `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />`

Now clean and run your application and it will run in 2.3 version.

Comment: I have made changes in my project according to your istructions but Manifest file Shows error "String types not allowed at" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

Comment: Sir, in manifest file I am using <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/> but still the same error araises

Comment: can you please post the code of manifest file..!!..it will make more sense

Comment: Ok Sir, i am going to post my manifest code. you can check it in posted questions. as comment the code can't be posted.

Comment: In your above question..you can edit it and add the manifest code at the down and you can Save the edit..no need to post a new question.

Comment: And please no Sir like Syntax...i am like you only...!!

Comment: Please check my Android manifest file i will be waiting for your response.

Comment: android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"

Just go on to remove the above line...it may be not support in 2.3.3 i hope so and may be supported in 3.2...this is not a researched answer but by remove this the error will get lost...

Comment: By removing the line now it runs on the android device but it shows a message in banner area "You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml with configChanges"

Comment: To use "configChanges" you should have your application build in Android 3.2 or higher, see the 

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals#requirements

So..it would not work in 2.3.3...
:(
I hope you are trying to restart the activity on orientation change or something like that..but for that min version required is 3.2...i have not used it before but on research i found that...srry if my information is proved to be wrong...but this was what i have found

Comment: Dear! thanks for your nice comments and I cordially appreciate your help, once again thanks a lot.

Comment: I have done what i admire to do..by the way..good support from you too..Thanks StackOverFlow!!